# Widget or layout to fill parent

Tags: qt, layout, qt5, qt-creator

What I'm trying to accomplish is a very simple and straight forward need, or I thought, but for the life of me, I can't seem to find a way to do it.

In my qt application I want to be able to make a widget or a layout fill the entire space of the parent widget.

For example, let's say I want to have a label with a fixed height and beneath it a stacked widget which occupies the rest of the height of the window.
Here's what I do in the qt-creator designer:

1. drag a label to the form
2. drag a stacked widget to the form
3. select both of them and then right click > lay out > lay out vertically
4. select the `verticalLayout` object and in the `layoutStretch` property have `0,1`

Now, how do I make the `verticalLayout` occupy all of the width/height of the `centralWidget`?
Nothing seems to work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've merely put two widgets in a layout, but you also need a layout on their *parent* widget - on the form. Here's what you should do instead:

1. Drag any number of widgets to the parent widget (the form). Arrange them roughly the way you want them to be once laid out.
2. Right click on the *form*. Select "Lay out >" submenu.
3. Choose the desired layout from the menu: horizontal, vertical, grid, etc.